# Laravel eager loading returns all results when querying realtionship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to get products with a seri name contains a certain word. However it returns all products. Matching serie name condition appears to be array under each related product; for the rest of products it is just a blank "serie" key.

```
$products=Product::with(array(
'serie'=>function($query)
{
    $query->where('name','like','%unky%');  
}))
->get()->toArray();
```

and array returned is like

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [updated_at] => 2014-02-14 22:26:04
        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [brand_id] => 1
        [cat_id] => 1
        [serie_id] => 1
        [devices_ids] => 1
        [color_code] => #BEB991
        [barcode] => 8699131462430
        [title] => Funky Charlie iPhone 5/5S KÄ±lÄ±fÄ±
        [desc] => Sert 6 gr
        [price] => 29.90
        [serie] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [updated_at] => 2014-02-14 22:18:31
                [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [name] => Funky
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (........


[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [updated_at] => 2014-02-14 22:46:10
        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [brand_id] => 1
        [cat_id] => 1
        [serie_id] => 2
        [devices_ids] => 1
        [color_code] => red
        [barcode] => 8699131462546
        [title] => Bonjour KÄ±rmÄ±zÄ± iPhone 5/5S KÄ±lÄ±fÄ±
        [desc] => Sert 6 gr
        [price] => 24.90
        [serie] =>
```

As you can see serie key is empty.
What i want is only to bring products with matching serie name and does not bring products like with id"5".
What i am doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think that instead of using Model::with(), you want to instead filter the Model, based on the related model, so you should use Model::whereHas()

```
$products = Product::whereHas('serie', function($query)
{
    $query->where('name','like','%unky%');  
})->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Eager loading constraints do not put a constraint on the results of the model - it constraints the related model. In your case, you get all Products. But if you try to access the Series of a Product, you will only get those Series that are true to your condition.

If you need to access the Series too and do not only need the Products, I would make the query like this:

```
$products=Product::with(array(
  'serie'=>function($query)
  {
    $query->where('name','like','%unky%');  
  }))
  ->whereHas('serie', function($query) {
    $query->where('name','like','%unky%');  
  })
->get()->toArray();
```

In this case, you get only the Products that are linked to a Serie whose name is like %unky%  and you get only the related Series that hold to the same condition.

To **sum this up**: whereHas restricts the list of Products based on the condition, whereas the Eager Loading constraint restricts only the list of Series for each Product.